# How can i improve my "compare" method efficiency?

Tags: c#

I have to compare dictionary with list, so i solve it like that:

```
public static bool DSCompare(Dictionary<int, int> d, List<int> l,) 
        => l.All(d.Values.Contains) && d.Values.All(l.Contains);
```

Two sets are equal if they contain the same elements.Dublicates are not important.
How can i improve method efficiency?

Comment: note: normally you'd check against a dictionary's *keys*, not *values* - as that is where the performance advantages of a dictionary apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a set operation, so use a set. An easy way is using `HashSet<T>`:

```
public static bool DSCompare(Dictionary<int, int> d, List<int> l) =>
    d.Values.ToHashSet().SetEquals(l);
```

Comment: it should be noted that creating the hash-set is far from free

Comment: It's true. However, if you've got enough elements that the code in OP's question is slow enough to need improving, the overheads of constructing the HashSet are *probably* small compared to the speed gain you get by moving to O(n+m) rather than O(n*m). As always, profile!

Comment: @canton7 great!